# How to make one value in an empty array shift left

Tags: c, arduino

I want to be able to have a character '0' at the end of the array of 15 space to shift left to the beginning of the array, then go back to the end of the array and repeat. This is what I got so far...

```
#include<stdio.h>

void printArray(int array[]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    printf("%d ", array[i]);
  }
}

int main(void) {
  int a [15] = {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '0'};
  int scrollLeft;
  printArray(a);
  int i = 0;
  while (i = 0) {
    printArray(a);
    scrollLeft = a[15] - 1;
  }
}
```

It's written in C, I want to be able to implement this code on my Arduino for a game. If someone could teach me what I'm doing wrong that would be great!

Thanks,
Ezrelle

Comment: I think you need to work on your understanding of how arrays work in C. Because all that the code you have is taking what's at position 16 in the array subtracting 1 then storing it in a variable, which isn't modifying the array. And since the array isn't being modified whatever is in scrollLeft will always be the same.

Comment: And another problem with this code is that you're declaring an array that holds 15 items but in the `{ }` expansion you have 16 items. So you need to change `int a [15]` to `int a [16]`

Comment: You also shouldn't use arbitrary values in your printArray function, I'd recommend keeping track of the arrays length in a variable and passing the length variable as an argument to the printArray function. By changing the function to `void printArray(int array[], int length)`. Then inside chaging the for loop to `for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code, some of which I have commented here. I encourage you to read up on some literature to familiarize yourself with the C language. As writing C code without much experience can be frustrating especially if you're not even sure with what your doing to begin with.

```
#include <stdio.h>


/*
    changed this function to take a length argument
    which will probably stop runtime errors with your version
    and added print for a newline at the end so that the lines dont pile up.
    could change that to a \r which would overwrite the line
*/
void printArray(char array[], int length)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) // changed to use new length variable
    {
        printf("%c ", array[i]); // changed this to %c to print characters
    }

    printf("\n");
}

/* 
    added this function which shifts the contents of the array.
    take a look at what it does, and try to understand why the temp variable is needed
*/
void scrollLeft(char array[], int length) {
    int temp = array[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < length-1; i++)
    {
        array[i] = array[i+1];
    }
    array[length-1] = temp;
}

int main(void)
{
    /* 
        this array should be of type char because you're assigning it with character values
        changed this so that the array is initialized with the proper size
        and added the length variable to store how long the a is
    */
    char a [16] = {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '0'};
    int length = 16;

    printArray(a, length);

    int i = 0;

    /*  changed from i = 0 to proper i == 0
        i = 0 assigns i to be equal to zero
        i == 0 checks to see if i is equal to zero
    */
    while (i == 0) 
    {
        printArray(a, length);
        scrollLeft(a, length);
    }
 }
```

And there are some ways to get this code to run faster if you want to create some of your own optimizations, as the scrollLeft code that I wrote doesn't take into account that the array only has one `'0'` and all other elements are `' '`.

Comment: An unstated but important reason for changing the type of `a` in `main()` from 'array of `int`' to 'array of `char`' is that the printing function expects a `char *` (or array of `char`) and not an `int *` (or array of `int`).

Comment: Thanks, you've been very helpful! I will study this code and try and implement it on my arduino.